# How to select an existing tag on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, tags

I spent a couple of minutes typing up my question about a problem I am having with Firefox, but couldn't figure out how to add the appropriate tag in order to get it submitted.
It said I didn't have enough history to start a new tag. Fine, but I cannot figure out how to get an existing one in there. It takes me to the tag page, but there are no instructions as to how to select an existing tag for use in a question. Each time I choose an exiting tag, it takes me deeper into that page.

So I gave up, again. This is the third time I have tried to ask a question, but have been stumped by the tag issue.

Would somebody please explain it to me? Now I get to try again.

Comment: Did you try just putting "firefox" in the tag section on the ask question page? Do you have javascript disabled or something?

Comment: That's not security, it's the idiot filter :-)

Answer (score 3):

Well, how did you add the [stackoverflow.com](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow.com) tag on your original question?

In the `tags` input on the question form, just start typing the tag name you want, you'll be shown an autocomplete for all tags matching your partial query, then just click on one of them, and it will be added to the question. You can have up to 5 tags on a question. Here on meta, one of the following must be on any question: [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), [support](/questions/tagged/support), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

You could face a problem if your browser is very old, or is not supporting JavaScript. Take note of that and if that's the case, **[Update](http://www.mozilla.org/he/firefox/new/) [your](https://www.google.com/chrome) [browser](http://www.apple.com/safari/)!**

Comment: lol at not linking the latest IE...which could have been hyperlinked under the '!', as in "omg, you could need even this!"

Comment: @DamienPirsy: Do you know the only reason IE is good for?

Comment: @Truth To find bugs?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: [To download other browsers.](http://www.makeuseof.com/tech-fun/the-only-thing-internet-explorer-is-good-for/)